# Дословный перевод блока вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Странная формулировка под цифрой: "-3 голоса"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это же рейтинг, а количество голосов в этом случае 3

Актуально для вопросов где много и минусов и плюсов может быть даже 0 голосов, при наличии равного числа и минусов и плюсов.

**Имхо такой перевод не корректен.**

Comment: Такой перевод **корректен**, как минимум, потому что в оригинале там **votes**. И это слово используется везде. Чтоб изменить именно в этом месте, нужно просить на MSE другой ключ для этого создать.

Comment: С другой стороны, **-3 голоса** читаем как **суммарно -3 голоса**. И всё ок)

Comment: я и говорю что перевод дословный, но не смысловой.

Comment: Всё упирается в то, что многие строки используется в разных частях сайта.

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю как работает локализация, и тем не менее

Comment: Я вроде как раньше на MSE видел обсуждение по поводу "голосов". Надо бы найти.